# Is this really John Bunyan?

Tags: support, users

I used to see the [J. Bunyan](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/1873/j-bunyan) and I thought it's just a nickname or a similar name. I checked the profile today, is he really the John Bunyan who wrote "The Pilgrim's Progress"?

Answer (score 7):

The [John Bunyan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Bunyan) who wrote *The Pilgrim's Progress* passed away in 1688. Unless you believe in reincarnation, I think it's unlikely that they are the same person. By a similar measure, just because his profile reprints extensive portions from *II Timothy* doesn't mean the profile author is Paul either.

Honestly I don't think either of the above historical figures had access to the several great resources linked in their profile or read their bibles using eSword. Those things tip me off that we are talking about a significantly more modern figure.

Comment: That is funny. That profile details fooled me